# Is there free windows ftp gui client that enable 2 remote locations side by side, instead of local+remote?

Tags: ftp

I need FTP client that allow me to move files in the server easily. I want to have side by side 2 server locations. In Filezilla for example I can see local & remote. I want remote & remote (in different folders).

Comment: You'll probably just want to run two FTP sessions in Filezilla or a  similar client and re-size the windows yourself to be viewed side by side.

Comment: Why you not use Windows Explorer. Then you can load two windows with different ftp addresses loaded!?

Answer (score 0):

Having remote and remote means that your FileZilla will also need to be run remotely.

The whole point of FileZilla is that it allows for large transfer of files from the system you're on, onto your server.

So if you want to transfer between servers, then you should run an instance of FileZilla on 1 of the servers itself and then do 'remote + remote".